# What's the differential of this function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

So, for some reason my business management major includes calculus and I am so not good at this, I have no idea what a differential is for, only that it is the variation between $f(x)$ and $f(x+h)$, so basicaly $f(x+h) - f(x)$

My teacher uses this formula:

$(f(x+h) - f(x)) \over h$

And I have no idea why on earth is it all divided by $h$

There is this function: $f(x)=4-5x$

And I put it on that formula like:

$4-5(x+h)-(4-5x) \over h$

Then expand it to

${4-5x-5h-4-5x \over h} = {-10x-5h \over h}$

And I can't get anywhere from there, but WolframAlpha says the result is $-5$ and my teacher's correction says it's $+5$

What is the correct result and what did I do wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $-(4-5x)=-4+5x$, so $\frac{5-5(x+h)-(4-5x)}h=\frac{4-5x-5h-4+5x}h=\frac{5h}h$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before you expand the expression,

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{4-5(x+h)-(4-5x)}{h} = \frac{4-5x-5h-4+5x}{h} = -5.$$

So that's how you calculate that quantity, but could it be that you're asked for the change going from $x+h$ to $x$ instead?  It all depends on how your text means "differential."  A business management text may use that word differently than a calculus text.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at that $h$ in the denominator is as $h=(x+h)-h$, so you have $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{(x+h)-x}$$
or changing a litte $x_1=x+h$:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{x_1\to x}\frac{f(x_1)-f(x)}{x_1-x}$$

You are comparing the change on $f(x+dx)$ with respect to the change of $x+dx$, if you see $dx$ as $h\to 0$ that leads to the other notation for derivates:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{(x+h)-x}=\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac d{dx}f(x).$$